# spark read xml database record as xml inputStream instead load from file path

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

From spark document

```
load(): DataFrame
load(path: String): DataFrame
load(paths: String*): DataFrame
```

I defined function which read a xml record

```
 def ExtractData(RecID: String,table:String)={
    val spark = SparkSession.
      builder.master("local[*]")
     .appName("Insight Application Big Data")
     .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "row")
      .load("src/main/resources/in/FBNK_CATEG_ENTRY.xml")//pass the xml record here
  }
```

How can I do if I want to pass the record which is in xml format to `.load` function, instead of loading from file, something like `.load(inputStreamXML)`

Comment: Write the InputStream to a temporary file... Otherwise, you need Spark Streaming and I don't think Spark Streaming handles multi-line XML very well

Comment: Do you mean read the all records from db then write it to file, then use spark to read of each file? (my db contains more than 9M records.)

Comment: If you're reading from a database, then I would suggest using JDBC reader... Your question appears to be reading a single file, however

Comment: thanks  can you help to provide an answer with sample using jdbc.

Comment: What's wrong with what you posted? Other than you shouldn't be using `.collect()` and `foreach(println)`?

Comment: I mean how we can read using jdbc , can you give me some samples.

Comment: The only example I have would be the ones on the Spark website...